# Best way to pass data not needed for rendering to parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am designing a simple mobile app with React Native where currently you should be able to create some data to store in my memory. For this there is a component which renders a menu with different text inputs or checkboxes. All the text inputs and checkboxes are in child components to better organize the code(eg. the parent component has children for setting type of data, value of data, different types of data need different inputs so the input menu changes slightly when data type changes, buttons for canceling and creating said items etc.).
 
Because the checkbox for a type is in a child component I have decided to lift state up like this:

```
function ParentComponent(){
    const [dataType, setDataType] = useState<usefulType>(typeT);
    const changeDataType = (type: usefulType) => setDataType(type);
    return (
        ...
        <ChildComponent 
            dataType={dataType} 
            changeDataType ={changeDataType}
        />
        ...
    );
}

function ChildComponent(props: {
   dataType: usefulType,
   changeDataType: changeDataType
}) {
    return (
    ...
    <Checkbox
        value={props.dataType == typeT}
        onValueChange={() => props.changeDataType(typeT)}
    />
    <Checkbox
        value={props.dataType == typeU}
        onValueChange={() => props.changeDataType(typeU)}
    />
    ...
    );
}
```

However doing it like this re-renders the parent component every time the checkbox selection gets changed, which I don't think is ideal. So I decided to use useRef like so:

```
function ParentComponent(){
    const dataType = useRef<usefulType>(typeT);

    return (
        ...
        <ChildComponent 
            dataType={dataType.current} 
        />
        ...
    );
}

function ChildComponent(props: {
   dataType: usefulType,
}) {
    const [currentDataType, setCurrentDataType] = useState<usefulType>(props.dataType);
    const changeDataType = (type: usefulType) => {
        setCurrentDataType(type);
        props.dataType = type;
    };

    return (
    ...
    <Checkbox
        value={currentDataType == typeT}
        onValueChange={() => changeDataType(typeT)}
    />
    <Checkbox
        value={currentDataType == typeU}
        onValueChange={() => changeDataType(typeU)}
    />
    ...
    );
}
```

Doing it like this makes only the child component re-render when the checkbox value changes, so I plan to do this for all input fields.
But after looking on other answers on SO people say that state in react is unidirectional and I should not pass it up, only down. How would the best way of going about this be? Sticking to the first option or another way althogheter?

Comment: First approach absolutely correct. You should understand react has render phase, when comparison happens, and commit phase when changes will be applied to the NodeTree. In your case only checkboxes will be updated because depends on dataType.